# СПП нерасчлененной структуры? Правильно ли?

Tags: спп

Пожалуйста, проверьте, правильно ли я нашла в тексте СПП нерасчлененной структуры:

1. Вёсла взлетали и падали сами, будто бы работал ими пьяный или сонный человек.
2. Телефонисты тут же мстительно вырубили важного начальника, который продолжал греметь в трубку отключенного телефона.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В приведённых Вами примерах только второе предложение можно отнести к нерасчленённой структуре (присубстантивно-атрибутивного типа).

***Опорный компонент: начальника, который***

Придаточное в первом примере относится ко всему главному предложению, это предложение расчленённой структуры.

Comment: спасибо вам большое